# how to create a box that hovers above existing text?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a dvd catalog website with a database of dvd images and informations such as titles/genre/year etc.

I need to create a text "Sort By". When you hover this word "Sort By", a box will appear just below "Sort By" and have several text hyperlinks such as "Title", "Genre", "Year" appearing. This box should overlap any existing images/texts on the website.

Is there a simple way to implement this?

Comment: did you have a look at javascript frameworks, such as jQuery or something?

Comment: @lbp Hi. Thanks for your input. I have not yet checked out jQuery. Is there any tutorials on that? Many thanks.

Comment: You can find pointers to documentation, contribs and subprojects at http://jquery.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with CSS only:

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<p>Sort By</p>

<ul>
    <li>title</li>
    <li>date</li>
    <li>artist</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container ul {
display: none;       
}
.container:hover ul{
display: inline;  /* or block or whatever you need */
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9QbGn/8/ (just hover over "sort by")

Comment: Thanks for your input, however this code is always hovering whenever I have a mouse cursor on the DIV. How do I make the box only appear when i hover on the word "Sort By"?

Comment: You need to hover over the div containing the list, here's an example with multiple items that each display a different list http://jsfiddle.net/9QbGn/29/.

Comment: Also, you need it to keep hovering while the cursor is over the options, without moving something below it, here's how: http://jsfiddle.net/9QbGn/30/